# System.Net.Http binding redirect when using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net core 2.0 project with a net47 class library. The library uses the latest version of the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client package.

When I copy and paste this dll into a completely different solution with a Webforms project and DataLayer class library both targeting .NET Framework 7.1.

The DataLayer in the Webforms solution also has Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client installed, but adds the following:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.2" newVersion="4.1.1.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I end up with the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

With a lucky guess I was able to resolve the issue by doing the following:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.1.1.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

How come I have to redirect to use version 4.1.1.2. Why can't it just work with version 4.2.0.0? And why is it requesting 4.2.0.0 in the first place? I am assuming the 4.2.0.0 is coming from the ASP.NET Core net47 class library reference.

Comment: the binding redirect from 4.2.0.0 to 4.1.1.2 made it for me, thanks!